# what is the point of SABR model as an interpolation tool if we can already observe the whole vol cube from the market

Tags: option-pricing, volatility, volatility-smile, swaption, sabr

on BBG and other data providers, it is common that you can find the whole vol surface/cubes. What is the point of the SABR model as an interpolation tool? why cannot people just linear interpolate the vol surface/cubes? instead of backing up the SABR params and interpolate on the param space? is it for the sake of non-arbitrage?

Comment: You can linearly interpolate, also in Bloomberg VCUB. However, often it's not linear and therefore, especially in between longer tenors and for extrapolation, it wouldn't be wise to just use a straight line.

Comment: Also the cube you are seeing there is not the real vol cube - its some broker or data providers best guess and is not guaranteed to be arbitrage free at a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

SABR is a stochastic vol model with the **vol parameter being a (stochastic) function of the underlying swap rate**. Yes, you can use market skew data and build a linearly interpolated swaption vol cube. But this cube entails **constant vols** based on the standard Black model, so it's a static structure. The SABR swaption vol cube is a dynamic structure that evolves as rates move - that's kind of the point of the model. This also entails significantly modified greeks... etc.

So you're comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: I guess following is probably true 1:) if you have a really dense grid with enough number of tenors/maturities/strikes, interpolation would be very similar between sabr and linear 2: on extrapolation, sabr can probably produce more reasonable number comparing with linear